# Google Script for sheets - populate data in different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I had purchased a bill tracker google sheets template and am trying to automate it so that if Year!I6:I is TRUE it will auto calculate the totals for each corresponding month in which the bill and category match. Using ChatGPT (I'm very beginner with scripts) I tried pulling this directly from the Expenses sheet, but couldn't get it to calculate properly. I created a sheet which calculated the totals by month by matching the categories, bill, and expense month (since the Year sheet does the first date of the month, I have a formula in Expenses!A:A to do first of month for the expense timestamp date so it all aligns (I do have another script that will be populating this in my original sheet).

I have hit a wall with ChatGPT and have spent about 6 hours chatting back and forth including starting the chat from scratch to try to get this to function. The latest script populates the expense totals in the first month column Year!AC where the bill and category also match, but I can't get the next months expenses to populate in the correct column (Year!AJ).

Here is a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SjsVhAXo95e7mge6Ph6BgP1Hxc9pdF2nc0GE6l8qzv0/copy?usp=sharing)

Please excuse all of the formatting (have not adjusted it since I started messing with the template sheet). Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

This is the last script I tried and I do have a time driven trigger for populateYearlyExpenses set up. When run, it is populating some, but not all of the values for Year!AC and it is populating a date in some of the rows in Year!AD when it only be entering values for the next months column (Year!AJ):

```
function populateYearlyExpenses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var expensesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("hidden exp");
  var yearSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Year");
  var expensesData = expensesSheet.getRange("A2:D").getValues(); // Assuming data in hidden exp sheet starts from row 2 and columns A to D

  // Get the range of dates in the Year sheet
  var dateRange = yearSheet.getRange("AC1:DB1");
  var dateValues = dateRange.getValues()[0]; // Assuming dates are in row 1 of Year sheet starting from column AC

  // Loop through each row of expenses data
  for (var i = 0; i < expensesData.length; i++) {
    var category = expensesData[i][0];
    var subcategory = expensesData[i][1];
    var totalExpense = expensesData[I][3]; // Assuming the total expense is in the fourth column of hidden exp sheet
    
    // Loop through each date column in the Year sheet
    for (var j = 0; j < dateValues.length; j++) {
      var date = dateValues[j];
      var columnIndex = j + 29; // Adjust for column offset

      // Find the corresponding total expense date in hidden exp sheet
      var expenseDateIndex = getColumnIndexByDate(expensesSheet, date);
      
      if (expenseDateIndex !== -1) {
        // Find the matching category and subcategory in the hidden exp sheet
        var hiddenExpData = expensesSheet.getRange("A2:D").getValues(); // Assuming data in hidden exp sheet starts from row 2 and columns A to D
        for (var k = 0; k < hiddenExpData.length; k++) {
          if (hiddenExpData[k][2] == date && hiddenExpData[k][0] == category && hiddenExpData[k][1] == subcategory) {
            // Populate the corresponding cell in the Year sheet with the total expense
            yearSheet.getRange(6 + k, columnIndex).setValue(totalExpense);
            break; // Exit the loop once the match is found
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function getColumnIndexByDate(sheet, date) {
  var headers = sheet.getRange("C1:N1").getValues()[0]; // Assuming dates are in row 1 of hidden exp sheet starting from column C
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    if (headers[i] == date) {
      return i + 3; // Adjust for column offset
    }
  }
  return -1; // Return -1 if date not found
}
```

I want the corresponding data in hidden exp sheet to populate in the appropriate amount due columns for the corresponding month in yearly. For example, Groceries should populate as pictured below[image].